# How to remove "Drupal" from title of page?

Tags: 8

Now I have this:

[image]

Here i found information how to change this text to anything else:
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2016-09-20/change-site-title-in-drupal-8

I tried:

[image]

But it doesn't help.

Drupal is 8.4.2

And it works on 8.0.6

Comment: Easiest way to fix this is use Metatag.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal by default will put the `site name` at the end of the page title but specific themes might change this.

if you want to override this your best bet is to use https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag module and override appropriate settings

There is a setting for first page or for all content types or specific content types; it very configurable.

Or you might do it programmatically in your THEMENAME.theme file:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {       
    $variables['head_title']['name'] = "Another Name";
}
```

To take away the `|` you have to create a new `html.html.twig` template in your custom theme and modify (copy paste it from the theme you are overriding)

```
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
```

to something like this

```
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join('  ') }}</title>
```

Comment: Why Should I install a plugin for just change site title? But, yes, this works.

Comment: @Crantisz so you don't have to re-invent the wheel and also Metatag is used for SEO.

Comment: It’s possible a theme or module did that. Metatag solves those woes easily, and a whole lot more.

Comment: Unfortunately metatag plugin change title only on front page...

Comment: Did you change the global defaults? Something else is really wrong here then, otherwise.

Comment: @Crantisz I would advise to change temporarily to the default a drupal theme and disable any modules that might change page titles and try again ...  something else is messing with your page title ... or please describe the steps you did maybe we can identify the problem ... did you clear cache ?